# JQuery: how to animate this addClass/removeClass tab menu? [JSFiddle]

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fdovctwe/

How can I take this menu in the link above and animate the class transitions so that they slide instead of toggling on and off?

```
        $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).click( function() {

            var tabID = $( this ).attr( 'data-tab' );

            $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).removeClass( 'current cola-sel' );
            $( '.tab-content' ).removeClass( 'current' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'current cola-sel' );
            $( "#"+tabID ).addClass( 'current' );

        });

        $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).hover( function() {

            $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).removeClass( 'cola-sel' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'cola-sel' );

        }, function() {

            $( 'ul.cola-tabs li' ).removeClass( 'cola-sel' );
            $( 'ul.cola-tabs li.current' ).addClass( 'cola-sel' );

        });
```

Comment: CSS transitions - you transition the height from 0% to 100% over a given timeframe -

Comment: what effect you really want?

Comment: I want it to slide.